# MidiClientCreate "The operation couldn't be completed. (OSStatus error -50.)"

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio, coremidi

I'm trying to debug a MIDI issue in a complex iOS / Objective-C software.
It appears on this call :

```
OSStatus s;
MIDIClientRef midi_client_ref;
s = MIDIClientCreate((CFStringRef)@"MIDIPlayerSetup MIDI Client", NULL, NULL,
                     &midi_client_ref);
```

Most of the time everything works fine but sometimes the returned OSStatus is a -50 code (bad parameter).

But as you can see and like in many example of MIDIClientCreate on the web, the explicit parameters can't really be the problem. I even tried to have an unique name with no effect.

To orientate my search, I would need to have a more precise idea of what is going on in the underlying client creation that could provoke this bad parameter issue.

Any guess is welcome !

**UPDATE :** someone got the same issue [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2013/Sep/msg00014.html) and solved it. He says "It was caused by an uninitalised variable.".

That's an indication, but not enough to lead me to my mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Apple and this is an internal CoreMIDI bug (until iOS8.3 at least) that was unknown until now.

### From the support :

> MIDIClientCreate itself will return -50 in only two scenarios:
>
> 1) If outClient itself is NULL so in the above you forget to take the address of client.
>
> 2) If the MIDI server has an issue getting a process ID back internally

I ensured the address of the client I provide is ok so in my case that is 2).

### Reproducting the bug :

I then noticed that I had several calls to  `MIDIGetNumberOfSources();` before the potential bug, so I implemented a sample app with in its delegate :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSLog(@"application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
        MIDIGetNumberOfSources();
    }
    MIDIClientRef client;
    OSStatus s = MIDIClientCreate(CFSTR("iMIDI Client"), NULL, NULL, &client);
    NSLog(@"OSStatus : %d", (int)s);
    return YES;
}
```

Running the app on iPhone 5 in iOS Simulator with iOS 8.3 (12F69) gives about 50% chances to reproduce the bug each time on my machine.